# Add noindex tag to specific URL

Tags: symfony, seo, googlebot

I have buttons and links in my Register page that allow me to log in with gmail and linkedIn. In order for these links not to be indexed, they have been indexed even though I have blocked them in the `robot.txt` file. How can I give these links a noindex tag?

here is the link that I need to block: `example.com/connect/linkedin`

**Note**: I don't want to prevent my register page from being indexed, so I don't use `noindex` in the `<meta>` tag. I am developing my website with Symfony framework.

Comment: on mysite.com/connect/linkedin use the noindex tag, also you can add rel=nofollow to the links pointing to that site, can you show how you blocked them in robots txt?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Don't those URLs just redirect to other sites?  If you let them be crawled, Google doesn't index redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Usually `rel="nofollow"` can be used to tell crawlers not to crawl those links, but since your pages are already indexed Google might do whatever they want at this point. try blocking the page itself from bots \ google, through the PHP code.